# How do I make sure that a declaration has a storage class or type specifier in C++ when using boost's program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am just beginning to learn about Boost for C++. I was following an example that uses the "program_options" library from boost. Below is my code. I am using Visual Studio and have already built the boost libraries that need building, added boost to the additional `include` directory, and added boost to the additional linker directories.

The issue is with `desc.add_options()`. Visual Studio says that this declaration has no storage class or type specifier. I am unsure of what that means and how to fix it. I have looked for solutions, but I have come up empty handed. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace opt = boost::program_options;

opt::options_description desc("All options");


desc.add_options()
    ("apples", opt::value<int>(), "how many apples do you have")
    ("oranges", opt::value<int>(), "how many oranges do you have")
;
```

Comment: You can't just execute code in the global space.  executable code needs to be in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *want that*. What the message implies is NOT that you miss some part of a declaration.

That line is NOT a declaration, and you should not be trying to make it into one.

What this is is a classic misunderstanding. The clash arises because the compiler **expects** only declarations at the global or namespace scope.
Since you used a statement, it cannot be interpreted as a declaration and hilarity ensues.

Fix it, e.g.:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace opt = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    opt::options_description desc("All options");

    desc.add_options()
        ("apples", opt::value<int>(), "how many apples do you have")
        ("oranges", opt::value<int>(), "how many oranges do you have")
    ;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what are the arguments for in this line `int main(int argc, char** argv)`?

Comment: `main` is the entry point for any C or C++ program¹. The arguments receive the command line parameters. They're optional, so you can just do `int main()` (or just `int foo()` of course, if it's not the entry point of your program!). However, I assumed you would want to parse a command line, since... you're using Boost Program Options :) (¹ although technically `WinMain` takes it place on some windows targets/compilers)

Comment: The whole point is that the code is correct IF you use it inside a code block.

Comment: Please, do yourself a favour and get one of these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list (some are available online)

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't think to put the code in a function.